# XSL select node with any attribute value using parameter

Tags: xslt

I have following xsl.

```
<xsl:param name="ip"/>

<xsl:for-each select="log/event[@ip=$ip]">
<!--content-->
</xsl:for-each>
```

I'm passing `ip` parameter. In some cases I need select each `log/event` not depending on `ip`. For example I want to pass `ip="*"`, and in this case I want to select all `log/event` nodes. How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<xsl:for-each select="log/event[$ip = '*' or @ip = $ip]">...</xsl:for-each>` should do. Just make sure that the asterisk `*` is not one of the values the `ip` attribute can have.

Comment: Yes this is the solution. @hek2mgl your "solution" does not depend on the parameter value at all.

Comment: @hr_117 does `*` depend on the attribute value? Btw, OP Wrote: `In some cases I need select each log/event not depending on ip` ... crazy comment, sorry!

Comment: @hek2mgl, I think `log/event[@ip]` does not take the parameter `$ip` into account at all and as far as I understand the question the parameter should be used to filter out `event` elements, unless the parameter has the value `*`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I've quoted the question. I think this cannot being misunderstood.

Comment: @hek2mgl, the question has a parameter named `ip` and an attribute named `ip`, so I think that is where your different interpretation of the question comes from. As far as I understand the poster wants to pass in a parameter value for the `ip` parameter and filter out events based on that parameter. For that he already uses select="log/event[@ip=$ip]`. But occasionally he needs to select all events and in that case he wants to pass in the parameter value `*`. Your interpretation seems to be solely on the `ip` attribute.

Comment: Yours is currently `+2 (accepted)`. It is likely that I'm wrong. (I don't see that at the moment, maybe tomorrow) .. However, thx for replying in discussion. :) aehmm.. +3 :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the attribute then use:

```
<xsl:param name="ip"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="log/event">
  <!--content-->
  </xsl:for-each>
```

If you just don't care about the value of the ip attribute but you want only select nodes which at least have an `ip` attribute use:

```
<xsl:param name="ip"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="log/event[@ip]">
  <!--content-->
  </xsl:for-each>
```